# Definition of universal generalization

Tags: logic, definition, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

In many places, I see the definition for universal generalisation given as follows:

**If $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi[x/t]$, as long as the term $t$ is not contained within any formulas within $\Gamma$.**

However, I often see this deduction, which seems perfectly valid but does not fit the general form of this rule:

$$P(a) \to P(a) \vdash \forall a(P(a) \to P(a))$$

That is, no substitution as such occurs, unless you consider it a 'degenerate' substitution, where $x$ and $t$ are the same term.

Therefore, if I'm being pedantic, the above definition of UG is unsuitable, we would need to also supplement it with:

**If $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$, as long as the term $x$ is not contained within any formulas within $\Gamma$.**

Would this be correct?  Or does the first definition implicitly allow the 'degenerate' case $\phi[x/x]$?

Comment: Why would it not allow that "degenerate" substitution?

Comment: Obviously, "if $Γ⊢ϕ$, then $Γ⊢∀xϕ[x/x]$ is the particular case where the *term* $t$ is $x$.

Comment: @DerekElkins  I don't have any reason to believe it wouldn't, I'm just not sure if that is allowed by the substitution syntax of FOL.  That is, does the syntax $\phi[x/t]$ imply that $x$ and $t$ must be different terms?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok that answers my question, the syntax $\phi[x/x]$ is allowed.

Comment: Correct. The derivation (with $\Gamma = \emptyset$): from $\vdash x=x$ to  $\vdash \forall x (x=x)$ is sound.